# Using libproc to get ports used by processes on macos

Tags: c++, c, macos, netstat, lsof

I am trying to get ports by processes. It can be done via lsof on macOS, i am trying to do it via libproc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libproc.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    pid_t pids[3072];
    int count = proc_listpids(PROC_ALL_PIDS, 0, pids, sizeof(pids));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        char buffer[1024];
        for (int j = 1; j < 50000; j++) { //port range
            int ret = proc_pidfileportinfo(pids[i], j, PROC_PIDFILEPORTVNODEPATHINFO, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if(ret != 0) {
                printf("proc_pidfileportinfo returned %d bytes of data\n", ret);
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
            }
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`proc_pidfileportinfo` function is not working for any port, i tried iterating till 50K. What i am doing wrong with `proc_pidfileportinfo`? how to properly use `proc_pidfileportinfo`?